# Using an array stored in params.yml to validate an entity

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints, yaml

I want to validate an entity using a values stored in an array which is in the params.

What I tried to do is injecting the array from `params.yml` (I'm using YAML) via service into a model.

In `validation.yml`, I tried to use the choice constraint with a callback. but I don't know how to call a method **non-static** from a different class.

To do this:

```
- Choice: { callback: [CountryHandler, getCountries] }
```

getCountries must be static.

Is it possible to do something like that with a method non static? Is it a *better idea** to validate the entity with my own constraint as they explain here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html?

I only have to validate one param and at first sight it doesn't seems a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a better idea because you can re-use in other case and better readability. As show in the documentation you give, you must create 2 files, one for your validator and one for the constraint, if you have dependency, you can inject to Validator declaring a new service with dependancy declared as arguments. After this, you have only to call your constraint as another Constraint.